# Looking for 5mm discrete multi color LED

Tags: led, rgb, optoelectronics, hobbyist

I want to make an electronic version of the `Master Mind` game as a hobby project. The challenge at the moment is to find right type of LEDs for the job. Below you see my draft sketch of the game board.

I want to have six 5mm multi color discrete LEDs per row of total eight columns for the player choice. These LEDs must be able to show 6 distinguishable colors

All I can find on eBay and Amazon are just RGB leds (the one with 3 pins, common cathode) that can be RGB or white. That is obviously not enough as I need LEDs that can produce at least 6 distinct colors for the 5mm LEDS.

Can you recommend  a part number suitable for this project?

I was thinking about addressable LED strips but that will be a bit ugly, I want discrete LEDs for optimal eye candy.

[image]

Comment: Stop looking on ebay or amazon and look on mouser or digikey.

Comment: How is RGB not enough, when you can produce R, G, B, yellow, cyan, magenta, white, pink, with suitable current ratioing?

Comment: @Neil_UK I was looking for just drive the pins from a GPIO pin of an MCU or FPGA...for current rationing I will require a complex circuit right?

Comment: If by complex circuit you mean 3 GPIO pins and 3 current limiting resistors, then yes. You'll then have 2^3 = 8 possible colours of black, white, R,G,B, yellow, magenta, cyan. You may need to adjust the ratio of the resistors to get the yellow, magenta, cyan colours well distinguished from the RG and B. If you want to drive one of the RGB at finer than on or off, then you'll need 2 GPIOs, two resistors for that colour, and then be able to drive that LED at 4 levels, perhaps necessary if you want pink, or an orange that's distinguishable from yellow.

Comment: If you're going to the complexity of an FPGA, then you could PWM the LED drives (at much more than 1 kHz please for people like me with fast eyes) to get arbitrary colours.

Comment: addressable LEDs in a 5 mm package do exist

Comment: First of all, product suggestions are off topic. Secondly,  you seem to have some misunderstanding how RGB LEDs create different colors. And third, I really don't see why would you ever want to do this with discrete LEDs, as addressable RGB LEDs exist, you can masquerade them to look like 5mm and 3mm LEDs with diffused light guides.

Comment: The WS2812B (https://www.digipart.com/part/WS2812B) is a 5mm x 5mm addressable RGB LED.

Answer (score 3):

Use smart leds like apa108 or ws2812b or whatever new flavor is out. **5mm Through Hole smart leds exist, they aren't all smd 5050.** You already have a microcontroller involved. It would reduce your pin count considerably, at 40 leds. Would reduce the number of supporting parts on board as well (resistors transistors etc). You'd only have to have 1 gpio. Pre-existing libraries will handle setting a specific color for you without massive color tracking and pam or charlieplexing. You could use a small microcontroller like the attiny probably but an off the shelf ATMega arduino or ESP32 would work with power to spare.. Setting a unique color would be as simple as telling it

Led5.Blue;
Led4.Purple;
Set.Leds;

Here is two example projects of mastermind with smart leds https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Arduino_Mastermind_Game.html https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=44313&p=221408&hilit=mastermind

You could use discrete rgb leds if you really want to (you masochist). Smart leds are just the same as a discrete rgb leds except they have a chip to handle the color mixing for you.

With discrete RGB leds you can set 7 colors just by selectively turning on the individual colors.
R, G, B, RG, RB, GB, RGB, Off. If you want more colors then you have to use pwm or bcm to modulate the colors.

Answer (score 1):

An RGB LED can produce any color you want, by mixing the red, green and blue.

For example, you can make yellow by mixing red and green.

This is exactly how for example your computer monitor works, it has only RGB.

Any standard RGB LED should work nicely for this project.

Comment: I was thinking that only 1 color can be on at the same time. so you mean if I turn on pins R and G I will get yellow?

Comment: Exactly. You can drive the three LED's individually. That is also how you make white as you mentioned yourself, you light all three at once.

Comment: @DEKKER: Yes and no.  With separate anodes and common cathode, yes.  That would be a 4 pin package.  Your question mentions a 3 pin connection (basically each pin is the anode of one LED and the cathode of another) and in that topology you can only get one color activated at a time (although with smart enough PWM going round-robin through the colors, it could visually appear as a blend to the human eye, although e.g. a digital camera wouldn't be fooled)

Comment: *"An RGB LED can produce any color you want, by mixing the red, green and blue."* Not entirely true... RGB LEDs still have a limited [color gamut](https://www.led-professional.com/resources-1/articles/avoiding-brightness-and-color-mismatch-with-proper-rgb-gamut-calibration). That said, I'm sure they would be sufficient for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @ben does that topology even exist? I'm sure they meant 3 pins + 1 common anode = standard 4 pin dumb rgb.

Comment: @Ryan: Of course, it can only produce an affine combination of the 3 component colors.

Comment: @Passerby: I've most certainly seen the 2 color 2 pin topology (where a positive voltage gives one color and a negative one gives the other), going to 3 colors arranged in a delta configuration is a simple extension of that.

Comment: @ben bi-color leds exist but I've never heard of tri-color in that configuration. Link?

Comment: @Passerby from ben's comment it seems he's only speculating that they might exist, if you want his attention you will probably need top "@" his full handle

Comment: @jas partials work too. The system notices previous people in a comment thread and makes an educated guess